# Activate/deactivate code

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uipangesturerecognizer

Trying to get the code so when `if whiteDotDist < centerRadius - whiteDotRadius` is executed all the code below it is active, and when the code below it is executed it becomes inactive again until the `if whiteDotDist < centerRadius - whiteDotRadius` is executed again. Sort of like a loop, so you have to keep going back and fourth from center to smallDot. Hard to explain over computer. Update it is giving me error 'Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGFloat' and 'Double'

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)


    let centerRadius = 37.5
    let whiteDotRadius = 23.5 

    let whiteDotDist = hypot(center.center.x - whiteDot.center.x, center.center.y - whiteDot.center.y - whiteDot.center.y)

    if whiteDotDist < centerRadius - whiteDotRadius {
  resetTimer()   }
    if (whiteDot.frame.contains(smallDot.frame) && smallDot.image != nil) {
        addOne += 1
        score.text = "\(addOne)"

        resetTimer()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(SecondViewController.startTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        smallDot.center = spawnRandomPosition()  
    }
    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: If you know the center and radius of both circles, you can use `intersectingPointsOfCircles:` function in this gist: https://gist.github.com/akhilcb/8d03f1f88f87e996aec24748bdf0ce78. If it is inside, it will return both points as nil. frame contains wont handle edge case for you where small circle is inside but frame is overlapping.

Comment: This is helpful, but it doesn't really answer my question. I tried to update the question to be more clearer thanks for the help!

Comment: by inactive, do you mean to say that you want to invalidate timer? Then in the else part call invalidate on the timer object. It will stop. Let me know if you want me to put this as answer. After adding an else clause to your if condition, it should work.

Comment: I mean like none of the code will work by inactive. It all won't work unless the whiteDot is in the center, then the code below it will all be active and working, then when the 'if (whiteDot.frame.contains(smallDot.frame) && smallDot.image != nil)" is executed that code becomes inactive again until whiteDot goes to center, so everytime whiteDot goes to center it activates the code below it, so it has to go to center then whiteDot every time.

Comment: yes, you should an `else` part to `if whiteDotDist < centerRadius - whiteDotRadius {` condition and then invalidate your timer there.

Comment: I am trying to get all of this code to become inactive if the whiteDot has not gone inside the center.                                                                                     if (whiteDot.frame.contains(smallDot.frame) && smallDot.image != nil) {
            addOne += 1
            score.text = "\(addOne)"
            
            resetTimer()
           
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(SecondViewController.startTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            
            smallDot.center = spawnRandomPosition()

Comment: But you need to activate when it goes to center again right? It is not possible that way. You can put whatever you dont want to execute in that if condition and when if condition fails due to circle outside bigger cricle, it wont execute any code inside. Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150359/discussion-between-zdp-and-adev).

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure:

1. All of the views have the same parent (so that they are all in the same coordinate system)
2. The Frames are tight around the circles.  Change the background color of center, whiteDot, and smallDot to Red and post a picture

Even if you do that, your code checks if the bounding rects are inside each other, so it may look like the smallDot is outside the whiteDot (if it were in the corner), but the bounding frame is enclosed by whiteDot's frame.

If you want to check that the circles (not bounding boxes) are inside each other, get the distance between centers and make sure that that is within the (outer radius - smaller dot radius).

pseudo-code

```
   let centerRadius = 100 // set this to radius of center circle
   let whiteDotRadius = 10 // set this to whiteDot radius

   let whiteDotDist = hypotf(center.center.x - whiteDot.center.x, center.center.y - whiteDot.center.y)

   if whiteDotDist < centerRadius - whiteDotRadius {
      // whiteDot is inside center
   }
```

Comment: One more question, how would I get it so when the "if whiteDotDist < centerRadius - whiteDotRadius" happens all the code below it is active, then when the code below it is exectued you have to go back to center to activate it again so you have to keep going back to center to activate code below. So you have to go to center, smallDot, center, smallDot. Hard to explain over computer.

Comment: Also I updated my code in this question and the code you put in isn't working.